# how to properly toggle between 2 dropdowns in react

Tags: reactjs, calendar, dropdown, toggle

I have 2 calendars collapsed in a bootstrap dropdown menu. The following code works, but it doesn't feel clean.

Calendar is a component from a react library. Onclick after selecting a date from the first calendar, I want to close the first dropdown and open the 2nd dropdown. What is the proper way to do this?

I am on React 18 using strictmode, so I also want to properly clean up with consideration to the double mounting.

What is the correct approach here?

```
//CalendarDropdown.js
const CalendarDropdown = ({date, onChange, open }) => {
    const elemRef = useRef(null)
    const monthYear = dateHelper.dateToMonthYear(date)

    useEffect(() => {
        if (open) {
            elemRef.current.click()
        }
    //What do I return here to clean up??
    //I also need to pass <func>onChange so that this always closes
    }, [open, onChange])

    return (
        <div className="dropdown" style={styles.dropdownButtonWrapper}>
            <button
                ref={elemRef}
                style={styles.dropdownButton}
                className="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" 
                type="button btn-outline"
                data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                data-bs-auto-close="outside"
                aria-expanded="false">
                <span>{monthYear}</span>
            </button>
            <ul className="dropdown-menu" onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()}>
                <Calendar 
                    maxDetail="year"
                    value={date}
                    onClickMonth={(date, event) => onClickMonth(date, event) } />
            </ul>

        </div>
    )
    function onClickMonth(date, event) {
        const isSet = onChange(date, event) //doesn't feel proper, but it works
        if (isSet) {
            elemRef.current.click()
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
//App.js
const App = ({startDate, endDate, setStartDate, setEndDate}) => {
const [toggleEnd, setToggleEnd] = useState(false)

    return (
        <div className="input-group">
            <CalendarDropdown date={startDate} onChange={handleStartDate} open={false}/>
            <CalendarDropdown date={endDate} onChange={handleEndDate} open={toggleEnd}/>
        </div>
    )

    function handleStartDate(date, event) {
        setStartDate(date)
        setToggleEnd(true)
        return true
    }

    function handleEndDate(date, event) {
        setEndDate(date)
        setToggleEnd(false)
        return true
    }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Store the calendar dropdown open states as two states in `App`, and as a prop (maybe `close`) to control the visibility of the cal in `CalendarDropdown`

On `handleStartDateChange`, set the `close` state for your start date Cal dropdown to false, and the close state for your end date Cal dropdown to true

Comment: thanks, I did that and it works. I updated (edited) my code to the working code and changed my question a bit. 

It still doesn't seem proper to me, and I'm also not sure whether or not I need to cleanup the useRef. I am trying to hack my way around to programically close, but I don't understand how bootstrap wired these dropdowns.